# dehydrate is not working for django tastypie api

Tags: django, tastypie

In my API I am using `def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):` method.

Now I need to append a dynamic field to provide some extra data.

So I am trying to use `def dehydrate(self, bundle):` method.

But in this case, `def dehydrate(self, bundle):` method is not executing. Again if I remove or keep in comment `def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):` method, then `def dehydrate(self, bundle):` executes.

In this case, how can I append an extra field (dynamic field) to my API ?

Comment: Need to see your Resource class, at a minimum the dehydrate method and the get_list method.

Comment: Here is my code:
https://codeshare.io/qUzsJ

Comment: Ok... now the issue is the opposite. That's way too much code to dig through. Just skimming it, you've over-ridden a lot of methods which seems like you are doing a lot more work than you need to. I try to keep my Resources much simpler than that. I suspect you are over-riding a method that calls dehydrate and replacing it with your own.

Comment: You are right. I found a reference  "The objects in the page have full_dehydrate applied to each of them, causing Tastypie to translate the raw object data into the fields the endpoint supports." here: https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html

That means **def get_list(self, request, **kwargs): ** method is overriding dehydrate. But what is the soution here?

Answer (score -1):

You're overriding the wrong method, use `obj_get_list` to provide the data not `get_list`.

Look into class `Resource` (`resources.py`), the line numbers refer to version 0.13.3 of django-tastypie:

- 1319: definition of `get_list`, dehrydrates the bundles in line 1339
- 1132: definition of `obj_get_list`, quoting the comment `Fetches the list of objects available on the resource`, this method is overriden in `ModelResource` and provides a working version for the Django ORM

You might also want to read up here https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html which explains which methods to override.